# Is it possible to insert a table in a fieldset?

Tags: wordpress, contacts

In a custom 'health form' field, I want to be able to fill in multiple pieces of information about medication; what it is, what it's taken for, how much, how often, when it's taken. Is it possible to have a table that allows each of these pieces of information to be gathered, relating to each medication? I.e. responding to each of the above questions about each medication taken. 
Or is there a different way to achieve this?

Ideally we could export this information, but if that's not possible I'd still settle for being able to gather the information in a logical way!

Perhaps the answer is as simple as multiple records fieldset? I'm trying this at the moment, but I'm not sure how to enter multiple records - or perhaps how to set the fieldset so that entering multiple records is blatantly obvious.

Obviously I'm no IT person, but your help would be wonderful!

Thanks heaps,
Kate

Answer (score 1):

See http://wp46.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fcustom%2Fgroup%2Ffield&reset=1&new=1&gid=4&action=browse where you have an example of a bunch of fields for

- medication
- frequency
- amount

is that what you need?

Comment: I can't access this... I need a login, but would be keen to see. Is there another way to see it?

Comment: use demo // demo

Comment: but the demo site gets flushed every day - now i am wondering what happened to my update to this ticket which had a screenshot - hmm. will be sad if we lost it, but easy to set up again. if you get stuck you can tweet me or something